# ReactJS - How can I change date format from MongoDB Date.now

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, date, schema

I'm using MongoDB and ReactJS.

So I want that user can see when created a new Project, but mongodb display this date format "2018-10-08 18:09:56.628" and I want to display only "2018-10-08". What can I do?

**My Project Schema:**

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

let projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  projectname: String,
  typeofproject: String,
  imageURL: String,
  dateMonthFrom: String,
  dateYearFrom: String,
  dateMonthTo: String,
  dateYearTo: String,
  tasks: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Tasks'
  }],
user: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
created: {
    type:Date,
    default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

**My React code:**

```
[...]
  <header>
     <div>
        <h1>

{this.state.project.projectname} // "Title"
{this.state.project.created} // "2018-10-08 18:09:56.628"

        </h1>

     </div>
  </header>
[...]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use some kind of formatting function. You could write your own using the built-in Date functions, but libraries like [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) (and potentially [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)) make it extremely easy.

```
moment(this.state.project.created).format('YYYY-mm-dd')
```

If you don't want to pull in a third-party library you can use the built-in [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) functions and write your own method.

```
function formatDate(date) {
    const currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    const monthString = currentMonth >= 10 ? currentMonth : `0${currentMonth}`;
    const currentDate = date.getDate();
    const dateString = currentDate >= 10 ? currentDate : `0${currentDate}`;
    return `${date.getFullYear()}-${monthString}-${currentDate}`;
}
```

Comment: The first one worked! Thank you :D my example:
<h1>{moment(this.state.project.created).format('YYYY-mm-dd')}</h1>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `mongoose` you can create a [**virtual field**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html) which could return to you the formatted date so that your react code can be cleaner.

You could utilize this function or use [moment](http://momentjs.com/) library (or many others)

```js
function dateFormat(date) {
    const month = date.getMonth();
    const day = date.getDate();
    const monthString = month >= 10 ? month : `0${month}`;
    const dayString = day >= 10 ? day : `0${day}`;
    return `${date.getFullYear()}-${monthString}-${dayString}`;
}

console.log(dateFormat(new Date()))
```

The virtual field setup would look like this:

```
projectSchema
  .virtual('created.formatted')
  .get(function () {
    return dateFormat(this.created)
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a little late but you can use the object Date like this:

```
const createdDate = new Date(this.state.project.created)
//Then, get the full year
....
{ createdDate.getFullYear() }
```

Doing that, u avoid use external library as momentJs.